# Attachment mandatory in Offering- self Service Center -Maximo

Tags: automation, maximo

We are using Maximo 7.6 and
we have several offerings where the offering owner has provided an attachment for the end-user to attach back onto the offering.
Unfortunately, we have not found a way to make the user's attachment required.
Does anyone have a solution for this issue? Perhaps an automation script?

I mean Offerings that are created in the offering application and seen by end-users in either the Self Service Center or the Service Catalog. These offerings create SR records.

Comment: You may want to review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  Unfortunately I wasn’t able to understand the question that you were asking so you may want to consider re-wording your question & providing your automation script that you tried and any errors received.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Offerings are a function of Service Cloud Control Desk.

At a high level, there are a couple of steps to configure (almost) any Maximo application to conditionally throw an error on Save.

1. Create a Message in Database Configuration to handle the error message.
2. Create an Automation Script with an Object Launch Point (On Save) to handle the various logic that goes into throwing the error.

There is a wide array of documentation and examples for creating Automation Scripts and validating records. My recommendation is to start by identifying the steps you need to accomplish in order to validate the desired attachment exists for the record, starting with isolating the change event where the validation should occur (you likely don't want this to happen on EVERY Save event).